# Regex Expression to extract data between braces and load into AMQ

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, amq

I'm developing a WinForm, C#. I have a data in a log file. I have loaded that data into a textbox. I got stuck while writing regex expression, I want to filter data between "[[" and "]]" present in a text box. I have this type of braces multiple times. and I want to load this data into the server using AMQ separately.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((stream = File.OpenFile()) != null)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        string patternstart = Regex.Escape("[[");
        string patternend = Regex.Escape("]]");
        string pattern = patternstart + @"(.*?)" + patternend;
        var tempdata = reader.ReadToEnd();
        str = Regex.Matches(tempdata, pattern).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value).ToList();
    }
}
```